# probable bug with dbbrowser

Tags: crash, sqlite3

Since recent update, i had to fix the batch loading code to load data into sqlite3 (V3.44)
adding :

> PRAGMA trusted_schema=1;

to solve an error message :

> sqlite> .import Enseignants.csv Enseignants

> Error: unsafe use of upper()

(upper() being used in a trigger on table Enseignants)
I found a hint at this url : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76342920/unsafe-use-of-virtual-table-when-creating-triggers-for-sqlite-full-text-search

but I am not sure why exactly this is needed (it is a 6 months old thread which states it has been fixed.
anyway this solved the issue).

However I also use dbbrowser  (sqlitebrowser which ids "DB Browser for SQLite Version 3.12.99 (Nov  6 2023)" )
When loading the same database, dbbrowser crashed right away and i do not get a chance to add the pragma.

Very annoying. (was working like a charm a month ago).

Thanks -
Christophe

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; but `sqlite` you mention matches `sqlite3 | 3.44.0-1          | noble           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` which is a *alpha* system and thus instability is to be expected, and that release is off-topic until it's deemed *stable* and thus a released system. Why not tell us what you're using?

Comment: Ubuntu 24.04 (*noble*) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *noble* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 18 April 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 25 April 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *mantic* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: Apologies for not posting in the first place Ubuntu 22.04.1 and in synaptic "sqlite3 3.44.0-0-20359-202311021114-202311041424~ubuntu22.04.1". I am confused as to why and how i would have installed an alpha version of  sqlite3; as far a i can tell the only non standard installs are brave, chrome, sqlitebrowser (linuxupising), slack, vscode, x2go-ubuntu-stable... I tried to remove the dbrower ppa just in case, then removed sqlite3 and dbbrowser and then "sudo apt update" to update list of packages, and reinstalled sqlite3 and DBBrowser. Versions unchanged. What did I do wrong ?